# Angular Builds Okay but NPM install Fails

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

How is it that a project can build okay but fail for npm install calls?

The project I'm on appears to be just a mess.

The npm list shows me that there are several peer dependencies that are not installed and extraneous packages.

I'm assuming extraneous are fine as it is just extras that are not used but if there are peer dependencies that are missing then how is it that the project does not fail when performing the build?

I'd love to paste the message output but it is on a different system that is not connected to this network.

Any tips are greatly appreciated as I learn this mess.

Comment: Delete the package-lock.json and retry. Sometimes that helps.

Comment: @Ludwig this project was a bit fubar. There was no lock file in the project. Running of the npm install deletes 150+ packages which several were needed and not specified in the package.json file. Appreciate the feedback. Finally after a week of a multitude of hurdles this project is capable of npm install as well as building it.

Answer (score 0):

Improper QA and code change management is the cause of this issue.